# Error 756 Too long request String when using onedrive file picker

Tags: javascript, http, browser, https, onedrive

i am using the onedrive filepicker for javascript

i developed a website where you can save a file directly
1. using the input element 
2. changing the file to dataURI format and saving it to onedrive.

using the input element is working perfectly  fine

but when i want to change to dataURI and save i get this error from the browser

```
Error 756 Too long request String
```

[image]

basically i uploading a .docx file and converting to dataURI and requesting save using the filepicker the dataURI is passed to the url request String which becomes very long

but upon some research based on this question

[What is the maximum possible length of a query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string)

the limit for chrome is 64k characters but when i counted the length of my request url it was 20,102

[image]

here is how the one drive file picker works you pass the parameters to an object and pass the function to onedrive.save function which takes care of everything including the calls and authentication also

```
  var odOptions = {
                          clientId: "1fd8b6bd-4585-4491-a802-7bc9f0fde5da",
                          action: "save",
                       // sourceInputElementId: "",
                          sourceUri: data,
                          fileName: "fil.txt",
                          openInNewWindow: true,
                          advanced: {},
                          success: function(files) { console.log('success');},
                          progress: function(p) { console.log("2"); },
                          cancel: function() {console.log("3"); },
                          error: function(e) { console.log(e); }
                        };

                        console.log("6");
                      OneDrive.save(odOptions);
```

can you help me why this is happening and how to solve this problem ?

my final aim is that in my other application i get the files from a server in the form of dataURIs and i want to save these to one drive

is there any other solution ?

you can test the website here https://bandrevu-akhil.github.io/

Comment: Have you tried using `FormData()` to post selected `File`?

Comment: No, i do not have idea of FormData() , even if that is possible we have to provide the dataURI variable to the onedrive FilePicker the url will remain same

Comment: `data URI` is only upload option?

Comment: yes you have to pass the dataURI as a pass a parameter to the onedrive file picker function rest it will be taken care of by it

Comment: hey i have added how the onedrive file picker function works